# Alamofire, Mocking & Type Returned is Apparently Not Same

Tags: ios, swift, mocking, alamofire, stub

So I'm mocking & stubbing out my request for the data with Alamofire and also using the ObjectMapper for it. This code was fine until this morning when I logged in and it saw it was complaining about this for whatever reason.

As one can see it says - "Cannot convert value of type 'Result<BikeShareCityResponse>' to expected argument type 'Result<BikeShareCityResponse>'". For me the value is the same type as the expected type so I'm a little confused by why this isn't working now...

I've cleaned the project, rebuilt it, deleted the DerivedData, and also restarted my computer. None of these have solved this issue.

I'm using Xcode 9.2 and my Mac is on 10.12.6

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Something might have changed at the server side. Possible ?

Comment: Maybe, its weird because the real service I created works. I get the data and I'm able to present it correctly.

I have this same setup in the production code but it doesn't give me this error like it does in the test

Comment: Also sadly I have no control over the real server. I have the current JSON structure saved to the project and its reading it in for this test

Comment: Compare the api on production server with that on which you are currently working. Do that on POSTMAN. It will give the error if it is on server end.

Comment: can you share the source of your response enum?

Comment: Well this code I've shown doesn't make a real HTTP call to the production server since its in my test class. The JSON is saved locally and I call it that way for parsing.

The actual code makes a request to the server and everything is completely fine, the data gets parse correctly and presented on the screen.

Here is the current code base for it
https://github.com/collisionspace/BikeShare/tree/feature/mapbox

Comment: @iOSDeveloper the response Enum which is the Result enum is created by Alamofire so I think it might be their problem. I'm contemplating on removing it from my dependencies and creating my own network call. I've used Alamofire extensively over the last 3 years and this is the first problem I've ran into

Comment: This is a Swift complier error, nothing to do with Alamofire. Are you using a library with a different `Result` type?

Comment: @JonShier Mhm interesting. It appears that only Alamofire has a Result enum,